# Regex How to match the first 2 instances of a specific character for Date Time string

Tags: javascript, regex, date, datetime

In JavaScript, I have a date format like this:

```
2023-11-02 10:00:00 -0700
```

I want to only match the first two instances of the `-` signs between the 2023-11-02, but not match the `-` in front of the -0700, and then replace it with `/` so that the final output would be

```
2023/11/02 10:00:00 -0700
```

I tried doing a regex match:
`("2023-11-02 10:00:00 -0700").replace(/[^\d\:\ ]{1,2}/g, '/');` but still matching the `-` in front of the -0700, and the output is `'2023/11/02 10:00:00 /0700'` which is invalid.

Comment: If input is always like this, you could even use a [word boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html): [`\b-`](https://regex101.com/r/gNhdq2/1)

Comment: The text you have is (almost) in a format [supported by the specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format). If the source can be modified to always output in standard format you might not have to rely on regex at all (although the `Date` API is crappy, it's still somewhat usable). See also [the `Temporal` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```bash
/(?<=\d)-(?=\d)/g
```

Here:

- `(?<=\d)` makes sure that there is a digit before matching `-`.
- `(?=\d)` makes sure that there is a digit after matching `-`.

Then replace it with a `/`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tcnGb3/2)

```js
const s = '2023-11-02 10:00:00 -0700';

var r = s.replace(/(?<=\d)-(?=\d)/g, '/');

console.log(r);
```